# How can I list class members as a data structures in c++

Tags: c++, data-structures, preprocessor

I'm trying to work on a user interface for my program, which I want to be extensible. I'd like to dynamically iterate over the data members of a class to expose them for editing. Is this possible? Something like the Unreal / Unity game engines in which you can code your class with some macros that expose the members.

Comment: C++ doesn't support reflection/introspection out of the box. There are some methods out there that can help you set this up but there's no standard way.

Comment: That depends. What are you using for your C++ interface? In Qt it's really simple to implement.

Comment: The Boost::Hana library may help you here, depending on your requirements - which in your case may be more easily solveable with a bunch of macros! https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/hana/doc/html/index.html#tutorial-introspection